# How do I get higher recording quality for my Nord Piano 3?

Tags: piano, recording, homerecording

this is the test recording I did

but when I compare to like these videos, they all sound way better

I'm using a UR22 interface with a TS patch cable I found lying around, I assume it is cheap and it's pretty short. this is a raw recording (OBS STUDIO) I haven't edited yet.

here is the recording that I did on audacity https://vocaroo.com/i/s0GgXoos4pSP

if there are any editing required like EQ, mastering stuff like that let me know and I'll send you the file so you can touch it up and send me how it should sound like after the editing

EDIT: this is another audacity recording but with 4.7 reverb hall https://vocaroo.com/i/s0Qi7I0yI5o1

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, it's not on-topic here to ask for someone else to edit or mix any of your content. We can tell you what we think will improve it, but this isn't the place to ask for services to be rendered. Also, vocaroo is probably not a good service for sending music files, since voice quality audio is often less than music quality, and vocaroo is meant for voice recordings.

Answer (score 4):

First off, everyone else recorded in stereo. The Nord piano library definitely sounds much better in stereo. You'll want two TS cables instead of just one. Also make sure you have all the effects on the Nord turned off since some of them convert the stereo piano samples to mono.

Anderton's has access to all the top-quality gear, so they might have run the two TS outputs into a stereo Radial JDI and then from there to some nice preamps and then from there to a high-quality interface.

Finally, it sounds like Anderton's compressed the audio a bit, which makes it overall much louder sounding without clipping. Since the piano is a very dynamic instrument, it is very common to compress it a bit to make sure the quietest parts are audible.

The others might not have compressed but start with stereo recording and see if that sounds good enough to you.

Comment: How do I compress it?

Comment: @SkyStar Well, with a hardware compressor or a compressor plugin, but start by recording in stereo first. I think that will give you at least 80% of the quality improvement you're looking for. It doesn't sound like the Boku-no Hero one was compressed, so if you like the sound of that, you might not need compression at all.

Comment: I see, thanks, I'll pick up some cables and make a new recording and we'll see the difference

Comment: so I manage to get 2 lines in, and I recorded it https://youtu.be/Q3kf0xiFmNM I think some parts there are some clipping or distortion, I don't know what the problem is, as I didn't even record the sound with high gain. anyways please give me some input on how to make the sound better :)